# Custom Metadata Contact FirstName and LastName not available

Tags: custom-metadata

I am using custom metadata with a field of type `Metadata Relationship(Field Definition)` to provide the config side of an app, however when selecting `Contact` as the object I cannot find the `FirstName` or `LastName` fields. Is this a bug, is there a way around this?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure they're not just somewhere else in the list? Sorting gets a little off sometimes it seems.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I just checked. It's not there...

Answer (score 5):

It appears that Compound Fields are not supported except by their "name pointing" field. For example, you can't select Mailing State, but you can select Mailing Address. I'm still looking for a specific document that states this, but it's obviously a limitation of the current implementation.

Comment: Hmm pretty sure I was able to use `Account.BillingCity`, `Account.BillingState`, etc. They all used `BillingAddress` as the label but did point to the component fields.

Comment: @AdrianLarson I've checked a few different fields, they don't appear as options when I try.

Comment: @sfdcfox thanks for confirming I am not going mad. I can work around it but have to add object/field specific check to what would be a pure dynamic method otherwise :(

Answer (score 2):

I know this one is a bit old, but found this today that might help.

Whenever you create a Metadata Relationship to Entity Definition (to get a picklist with the SObjects) you get the option to create two additional Metadata Relationships

- Field Definition
- Entity Particle

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.custommetadatatypes_relationships_field_particle.htm&type=5

When choosing Entity Particle that gives you a picklist with all fields including compound fields (FirstName, LastName)

[image]